# Is it possible to update existing Data Validation help text?

Tags: google-apps-script

In Google Sheets, I created a Data Validation dropdown and added some help text manually. When trying to change the existing help text from a script, it does not work. There is very little documentation out there on this, so it's been impossible to overcome.

```
// update help text
var rule = active_range.getDataValidation();
ui.alert(rule.getHelpText()); // Returns existing help text                 
rule.setHelpText('workout2'); // Code breaks here
active_range.setDataValidation(rule);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You want to modify the existing the Data Validation rule.
- You want to modify the help text.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
rule.setHelpText('workout2'); // Code breaks here
active_range.setDataValidation(rule);
```

#### To:

```
var modifiedRule = rule.copy().setHelpText('workout2').build();
active_range.setDataValidation(modifiedRule);
```

- At first, copy the existing rule and set the help text. Then, the modified rule is set to the range as the Data Validation rule.
- In my environment, `var modifiedRule = rule.copy().setHelpText('workout2');` could be also used.

#### References:

- [copy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation#copy())
- [setHelpText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#sethelptexthelptext)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Adam Glazier Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.